# Python 3: thread not run

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have the following module:

```
import threading
import time


class searchVolume(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self, results):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)


   def run(self):
      print('Custom thread function.\n')
      print('Custom thread function1.\n')
      print('Custom thread function2.\n')
```

In the module `main.py` I have the following code:

```
searchVolumeThread = searchVolume()
searchVolumeThread.start()
```

The contructor class is called but when I call the `start()` method, in the terminal console I see the output "Terminated" without any print.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The code you posted throws an exception, and if I fix that part of the code, then it works as expected.

Comment: Your tag is `python-2.7` but the question says "Python 3" - can you clarify?